# IllegalStateException using custom adatper and AlertDialog Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, illegalstateexception

I have a multiple ListView(s) in my activity wich are using the same CustomAdapter.
In my CustomAdapter, on each ListView I add an image to the single item of the ListView in condition.

I just want to manage the Image On Click Listener (in my CustomAdapter) and Display a custom AlertDialog.

But I only want to draw on this AlertDialog the contents of an ArrayList

I found this first solution : programmatically make a LinearLayout and filling it with my ArrayList of Dictionary

EDIT : Here is MyAdapter (I make my adapter more simple in order to you understand):

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Drink> 
    {
            LayoutInflater inflat;
            private ArrayList<Drink> items;
            private String sousCategory;

            public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Drink> objects) 
            {
                super(context, R.layout.activity_sousboissons_list_item_elementsouscategorie, objects);
                this.items = objects;
                this.inflat = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                this.sousCategory = objects.get(0).getType();
            }
           private class ViewHolder{
                public TextView title;
                public TextView prix;
                public TextView desc;
                public TextView size;
                public ImageView img;
                public LinearLayout ll;
            }

           @Override
           public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
               String currentKey = "";
               ViewHolder holder = null;
               Drink element = items.get(position);

               if (convertView == null) {
                       holder = new ViewHolder();
                       convertView = inflat.inflate(R.layout.activity_sousboissons_list_item_elementsouscategorie, null);
                       holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sousboissons_element_title);
                       holder.desc =  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sousboissons_element_desc);
                       holder.prix =  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sousboissons_element_prix);
                       holder.size = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sousboissons_element_size);

                       if (element.getPrice().size() > 1){
                                  EditText editT = new EditText(SousBoisson.this);
                           final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(SousBoissonsActivity.this);
                           alert.setTitle(element.getName());
                   alert.setView(e);
                           holder.img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                alert.show();
                            }
                        });
                           holder.ll.addView(holder.img);
                       }else{
                       }
                       convertView.setTag(holder);
               } else {
                       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
               }
               if (element != null) {
                   // Here I'm setting all the Text Value of my Labels
                   }
               }
               return convertView;
           }
    }
```

It works well but when I click a second time on it I've an error :

```
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3618)
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3489)
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3465)
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:402)
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:242)
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:336)
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:351)
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:256)
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at azur.mobile.incomrestau.SousBoissonsActivity$MyAdapter$1.onClick(SousBoissonsActivity.java:189)
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
03-27 19:50:11.007: E/AndroidRuntime(5416):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've read that was normal because I'm in a child so I cannot replace him..

I thought to use `alert.setAdapter` instead of using `alert.setView` but I don't know..

EDIT : The problem is not from my `holder.ll`..

Comment: What is this ? holder.ll.addView(holder.img);.. holder.ll is null

Comment: I just set programmatically a clickable image on my layout

Answer (score 0):

> It works well but when I click a second time on it I've an error:
>
> ```
> IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
> ```

This seems to be the problem line:

```
holder.ll.addView(holder.img);
```

A quick fix is to check if `img` already has a parent and if it does remove it:

```
if(holder.img.getParent() != null)
    ((ViewGroup) holder.img.getParent()).removeView(holder.img);
holder.ll.addView(holder.img);
```

Comment: Indeed, I gave your comment above an upvote.  I'm not certain how this code works, it could just be an error here in the question.  I focused on the author's claim that "It works well [the first time]" and searched for the most likely cause of the exception shown.

Comment: nothing append bad with my image but, as you can see now, I've the same error when I just put an EditText on the alertDialog and when I click for the 2nd time on the image..

Answer (score 0):

Oh it works using remove view in the OnClickListener of my img !!

I just added :

```
holder.img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    if(e.getParent() != null)
                                        ((ViewGroup) e.getParent()).removeView(e);
                                    alert.show();
                                }
                            });
```

:) thank you, hope it will be working with custom a custom layout instead of an editText.